# creating a dynamic menu using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, menu

this is what I need to genarate

```
<ul id="0">
 <li >1</li>
   <ul id="1">
      <li > 11</li>
      <li > 12</li>
   </ul>
 <li > 2</li>
   <ul id="2">
      <li > 21</li>
      <li > 22</li>
   </ul>
 <li > 3</li>
<ul>
```

this is my "menu_item" table

```
id            int(11)
title         varchar(75)
link          varchar(100)
parent_id     int(11)
position      int(11)
```

//parent_id of 1st layer(menu categories) is 0

I got the table rowset order by parent_id and position by

```
SELECT 'id','title','link','parent' FROM 'menu_item'
ORDER BY 'parent_id' AND 'position';
```

I don't know how to generate the html code for the menu using this data.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ref 1](http://www.chipchapin.com/WebTools/MenuTools/)
[ref 2](http://www.finalwebsites.com/tutorials/dynamic-navigation-list.php)